# How to add a table that has a key off of the roles table in the SimpleMembership setup?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, simplemembership

I have a web app setup with Simple Membership and Entity Framework Code first Migrations.  I would like to create a POCO class that has a many-to-many relationship with the webpages_roles table in the database.  It appears as though that table is created in the back end and not created with a std. EF POCO class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good tutorial [here](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) that shows how to make the Simple Membership tables part of your entity data model. May put you in the right direction.